# how can I only allow a user to select only one checkbox (bootstrap checkbox)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

**I added bootstrap checkboxes in my code, but the user should be able to select only one checkbox, the others get unchecked automatically. But I m not able to do that, can someone tell what should I add in my code please**
[Here is the screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjxJc.png)

```
<div class="form-check form-switch" style="display: flex;">
                               
     <label class="form-check-label" for="uo1">UO1</label><br>
     <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="uo1" id="uo1" value="0" />
     
      <div id="uo1div" style="display:none">
       <BR> TJM = 225 €
      </div>
                                 
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#uo1').change(function() {
           $('#uo1div').toggle();
      });
   </script>

</div>
```

Comment: It would be probably easier to use radio buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a radio type input, not check boxes. Each input gets a unique id and value, but the same name to put it in a "radio group."
See https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="uo" id="uo0" value="0" />
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="uo" id="uo1" value="1" />
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="uo" id="uo2" value="2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use radio button instead. and add css which look like checkbox. or you can use javascript or jQuery to uncheck all checkbox and then check current one.

Comment: Thank you it worked with the radio button